# How to change the default colors in Calender Overlay settings?

Tags: calendar

Rather than modifying the css, is there any alternative way to change these default colors? From which lists are these colors populated?

Comment: Similar question: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/75674/how-can-i-change-the-default-color-for-calendar-events-without-overlaying?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

The [following solution](https://davidlozzi.com/2012/06/20/customize-the-sharepoint-calendar-colors/) details a way to insert a new stylesheet that overrides the lower level css.  This is a no code solution that doesn't require admin permissions and is very popular with users.